# Tomcat 5.5 Giving an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: tomcat5.5

I hosted a jsp service to access a java class to send a request to a server. I hosted this service in Tomcat 6.0 server hosted in my local computer and it worked fine. But when I tried it with another server which has Tomcat 5.5 I'm getting this error.

Error report is given below. I'll be really grateful if someone can help.

Error Report

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.access$11(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl$12.run(PageContextImpl.java:761)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:759)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:963)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:628)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:776)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:741)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:288)
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    hiit.audioimager.ImageRetriever.getNopsaImages(ImageRetriever.java:86)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing Tomcat6 and uninstalling tomcat5.5. The problem was caused by the directories where we stored them and the java library path. They all have to be set properly. So apt-get installation is not advisable. Better download the tar and install it manually.